# concatenate images to make a bigger image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, gps, mapping

I have some images that their file name are corresponding GPS data (Long/Lat), and I'm trying to use preferably MATLAB to put them together and make a bigger image! In other words, I want to creat a local map by having several aerial pictures.
anyone has any idea or knows any software that really works to concatenate some images to make a bigger image?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what type of images you have.

If you have georeferenced images, in GeoTiFF or other format, the [Matlab Mapping Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/products/mapping.html) is very good for loading geographic imagery, manipulating it, and displaying it.

If you just have images that aren't georeferenced, you can use the [Matlab Computer Vision Toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/feature-based-panoramic-image-stitching.html) to register the images and stitch them together like a panorama.  Photoshop also has some powerful panorama stitching tools if you don't need to do it programmatically.

Comment: The problem is images have overlap and there should be an algorithm to skip those part of image ...